# Kernel panic after trying to update to Sierra [OSX]

Tags: macos, mac, kernel, kernel-panic

We tried to update to Sierra last night and the progress bar pretty much stuck during the installation. Now we can only boot in safe mode, but that's it.

[Here's Crash Log since I couldn't paste it here](https://ru.scribd.com/document/326600086/Kernel-2016-10-06-072202-MacBook-Pro-Anna)

All the files from my my System/Lirbary/Extensions

Could somebody give us ideas how to fix it? We tried to update Sierra from safe-mode, but had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

None of these should be on a real Mac, they are all hacks present on a Hackintosh installation.

```
loaded kexts:  
org.slice.HWInfo 1  
org.slice.IntelCPUMonitor1.1  
org.netkas.FakeSMC
```

If it's a real Mac, then you need to get rid of them.

To unload then delete a kext you need to use these commands in Terminal. If you are booted from Recovery, then they will be on the normal boot drive so I think you'll have to specify the full path - try both - replace [names] with the correct name

Standard command
`sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/[kextName.kext]`
Full path version
`sudo kextunload Volumes/[HDname]/System/Library/Extensions/[kextName.kext]`

Then, remove the kext folder so doesn't autoload on next boot:
`sudo rm -r /System/Library/Extensions/[kextName.kext]` or
`sudo rm -r Volumes/[HDname]/System/Library/Extensions/[kextName.kext]`

Comment: How exactly do we get rid of it?
It is a real mac as far as I know

Comment: Removal instructions added to answer - but I'd really wonder where they came from. Don't trust OS X installers from anywhere other than Apple themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions! However, there are no such files in System/Library/Extensions folder

Comment: I added the list of my System Extension kexts to the original post

Comment: Are you looking at the correct system? If you are booted to recovery, then 'system' will be the one in recovery, not the main HD. There ought to be something like 300 kexts in the main system folder

Comment: Oh thanks for explaining that! Weird that I couldn't do anything before. Is it weird that I still cannot find org.sliceHWInfo there?
The only one I found it FakeSMC and Im going to delete it and try to boot

Comment: tbh, I've never seen a system with them present, so idk what names they may actually have in that folder, sorry